# Reproducing git merge conflict: AU

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I'm working on a test script and trying to reproduce git merge conflict AU (unmerged, added by us)

I keep coming up with either AA, or UU with everything I try. Example:

- Create repo
- Create/stage/commit test file
- Create source branch, update/stage/commit test file
- Checkout master, delete/stage/commit test file
- Create target branch, add/stage/commit test file
- Attempt merging source branch to target branch

UU conflict is produced, which is not what I'm looking for.

What steps do I need to perform to generate AU conflict?

Comment: To clarify - in my production repo I have seen "git status -s" report AU conflict. I'm trying to figure out how to recreate this conflict file status manually, for testing.

Comment: I'm going to kill off my first comment as it's too misleading (since we're talking more about how `git status --short` *presents* these).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Here's the sequence of events:

- Create/stage/commit file1 on master
- Create source branch from master
- Remove/stage/commit on source branch
- Checkout target branch from master
- Rename/stage/commit file1 to file2
- Merge source branch to master

Conflict ends up with "AU" when running git status -s

Comment: That produces a rename vs delete conflict (`CONFLICT (rename/delete): file2 deleted in b1 and renamed in HEAD. Version HEAD of file2 left in tree.`). The merge base has the file as `file1`, one tip has no file, the other tip has file matching [see note] `file1` but named `file2`. This does in fact turn out to be listed in `git status` as added-but-unmerged, though. (Notes: 1: You don't need to commit a modification, just a delete. 2: "Matching" means within the rename detection threshold. An exact match always matches, but a close match suffices.)

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer to remove the unnecessary modification.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on [Pavel Chernikov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43700415/1256452), here is a shell script<sup>1</sup> that literally produces the correct conflict.  Note that this particular rename/delete conflict is announced as `AU` by `git status --short`, since the renamed file is left in the index and work-tree, but in the stage-2 (i.e., `--ours`) index slot.

```
#! /bin/sh

SELF=$(basename "$0")

if git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null; then
    echo 'this must be run in a temporary dir that is not a git tree'
    exit 1
fi
files="$(ls -A)"
if [ "$files" != "" -a "$files" != "$SELF" ]; then
    echo "this temporary dir has too many files"
    echo "(should be empty or contain only \"$SELF\")"
    exit 1
fi
echo 'initializing new Git repository'
git init >/dev/null || exit 1
echo 'demonstrate rename vs delete conflict' > README
cat > file1 << 'end'
here is a file
it is named file1
at least it is, initially
it has a bunch of contents
so that it's clear that this is the same file
even after we rename it.
end
echo "$SELF" > .gitignore
git add README file1 .gitignore
git commit -q -m initial
git checkout -q -b b1
git rm -q file1
git commit -q -m 'remove file1'
git checkout -q -b b2 master
git mv file1 file2
git commit -q -m 'rename file1 to file2'
echo 'the next merge will have a rename/delete conflict:'
git merge b1 | sed 's/^/    /' 2>&1
echo
echo 'however, git status --short shows AU:'
git status --short
# clean up
rm -rf .git README file2 .gitignore
```

Running the script produces:

```
initializing new Git repository
the next merge will have a rename/delete conflict:
    CONFLICT (rename/delete): file2 deleted in b1 and renamed in HEAD. Version HEAD of file2 left in tree.
    Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

however, git status --short shows AU:
AU file2
```

We can swap the merge around, so that `--ours` is deleted while `--theirs` is kept (so that the retained index entry is in slot 3).  This is just a matter of starting in branch `b1` and then merging the commit whose tip is identified by `b2`

```
git checkout -q b1
git merge b2
```

The complaint is now:

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): file2 deleted in HEAD and renamed in b2. Version b2 of file2 left in tree.
```

and the `git status --short` output has the `AU` swapped to suggest the slot changes:

```
UA file2
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This uses only `sh` features but will also work in `bash`.

Comment: any idea what the logic would be to reproduce conflict that results in git --short status DD?

Comment: Hm, have you ever seen `DD`? It can occur in the index as "present in stage 1 but not stage 2 or 3" but that should never occur as a result of `git merge`. Similarly, `DU` and `UD` are possible staging combinations but should never by set by any of the built in merge strategies. You can create these states using `git update-index --index-info`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw several DD's recently, but had trouble reproducing. It has something to do with a combination of adding a file on common, then deleting/renaming on source and target branches.

Comment: The thing is, "present in base, deleted in tip1, deleted in tip2" is not a conflict. Git resolves this by deleting the file. Rename detection will not affect this at all since the state of a file-pair (in either base-to-tip1 or base-to-tip2) can only be one of four possibilities: not-modified-at-all, modified-but-not-renamed, renamed-but-not-modified, or renamed-and-modified. There is no such thing as "renamed-and-deleted" in a single base-to-tipN.

Comment: Found a link to https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t7060-wtstatus.sh. It's kind of hard to read, but it contains test code for all git conflict types.

Comment: @PavelChernikov: aha, that has the clue needed to see how `git status` shows a `DD` state.  It's not really deleted at all: it's renamed twice, once in each tip (as compared to the base). The merge step prints: `CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "file"->"b2name" in branch "HEAD" rename "file"->"b1name" in "b1"` and the short status as one `UA`, one `AU`, and one `DD` to cover the three index entries. (Hence, I was wrong in claiming "rename detection will not affect this at all": it has no overall effect if there's *one* rename but causes a conflict if there are *two different* renames.)

Comment: @alper: the same way you resolve any conflict: (1) Determine the *correct set of files* that should be in the next commit (by using your brain: there's no computerized shortcut for this step). (2) Create those files in your working tree, by any means you choose (there may be shortcuts *here*, but step 1 is required first, and *step 1 will determine the available shortcuts* - hence the lack of a Royal Road To Geometry). (3) Run `git add` on those files to update Git's index.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, and [Pavel Chernikov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43700415/37899) didn't quite work for me (I got UD I think), but this worked for me (similar or same to torek's answer, but for Windows):

```
git init
echo 1 > 1.txt
git add 1.txt
git commit -m "add 1.txt"
git checkout -b a
git mv 1.txt a.txt
git commit -m "rename 1 -> a"
git checkout main
git mv 1.txt main.txt
git commit -m "rename 1 -> main"
git merge a
git status --short
```

outputs:

```
CONFLICT (rename/rename): 1.txt renamed to main.txt in HEAD and to a.txt in a.

DD 1.txt
UA a.txt
AU main.txt
```